# Django Managers or a better plan

Tags: django, django-managers

I'm just getting my hands on [Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) and I've found myself doing this type of programming.  I'm looking to see if there is a way to remove the obvious repetition..  I believe I need to define use `get_query_set` to refer to myself?

To be very clear on my question.  I am repeatadly having to pass in the subdivision in order to figure out the rows from which to filter on.  I think there is an easier way I'm just not sure what it is.

Thanks for looking!!

--- models.py

```
class Subdivision(models.Model):
    objects = SubdivisionManager()
```

--- managers.py

```
class SubdivisionManager(models.Manager):
    """A generic manager with metros"""


    def is_metro_sample_eligible(self, subdivision_id):
        """Are we eligible for sampling taking into account the 90 day windows"""
        from .models import Subdivision
        subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(id=subdivision_id)
        return True


    def get_available_subdivisions(self, subdivision_id):
        """Return all potential subdivisions for a builder in a metro"""
        from .models import Subdivision
        subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(id=subdivision_id)
        return self.filter(builder_org=subdivision.builder_org,
                           metro=subdivision.metro)

    def get_available_sampling_subdivisions(self, subdivision_id):
        """Return Subdivision which are able to participate in metro sampling"""
        from .models import Subdivision
        subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(id=subdivision_id)
        return self.filter(builder_org=subdivision.builder_org,
                           metro=subdivision.metro,
                           use_sampling = True,
                           use_metro_sampling = True)
```

Comment: You have `SubdivisionManager` in the first block of code but `SubdivisionMetroManager` in the second. Is this a typo? Also, `is_metro_sample_eligible` seems to be lacking a return.

Comment: You are correct!  Midstream modification - Sorry bout that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'd put `is_metro_sample_eligible()` on `Subdivision`, since each call needs to access an instance.

```
class Subdivision(models.Model):
    def is_metro_sample_eligible(self):
        """Are we eligible for sampling taking into account the 90 day windows"""
        #TODO do something useful here and return true or false
        return True
```

And then I'd either move `get_available_subdivisions()` and `get_available_sampling_subdivisions()` onto your `builder_org` model

```
from .models import Subdivision

class BuilderOrg(models.Model):
    #whatever you have goes here
    def get_available_subdivisions(self, metro):
        """Return all potential subdivisions for a builder in a metro"""
        return Subdivision.objects.filter(builder_org=self,
                                          metro=metro)

    def get_available_sampling_subdivisions(self, metro):
        """Return Subdivision which are able to participate in metro sampling"""
        return Subdivision.objects.filter(builder_org=self,
                                          metro=metro,
                                          use_sampling = True,
                                          use_metro_sampling = True)
```

or leave it on the manager, and revise the signature to `get_available_subdivisions(self, builder_org, metro)`.

Rationale- I could imagine needing to call `get_available_subdivisions()` without actually having a `Subdivision` already in mind- clearly the important pieces of information are the builder organization and the metro.

Comment: This is interesting.  I completely agree with you on the first one and have already done that.  While I understand with your rationale for the second and third methods; logically I would think to query a Subdivision model for subdivisions.  That is what drove me to figuring out a way to shoe-horn this into a manager.  Ideally it would be a somewhat dynamic Manager.  There are a few ideas on how to do this (http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/) but I'm not sure they apply here.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think I'm more in favor of changing the method signatures on `get_available_subdivisions` & `get_available_sampling_subdivisions`- that way you still get model classes returning model instances, but you have more flexibility than passing in a `Subdivision` instance.